# couchdb pagination with complicated queries

Tags: pagination, couchdb

For example, we have text filter such as

docs = db.view("_design/filter/_view/substr", startkey=substring, endkey=substring + u"\ufff0", include_docs=True, limit=20, skip=0)

what is the right way to make pagination without slow skip?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I hope you understand that this is not fulltext-search. You also can't implement pagination in CouchDB without using a skip parameter, because you can't say where (say) 20th element is placed. So the only way to simulate pagination is to make "next N results" link/button.

Comment: Сan give an example, may be can be done with lucene  implement pagination?

Comment: @AlikZao: Is [this tip from Robert Newson](http://couchdb.markmail.org/thread/bdjvscg3trshjn4j) of some help?

Comment: This is not full-text search however I suggest that people start this way. Prefix (autocomplete) search is very valuable, and you'll learn CouchDB views very well. CouchDB-Lucene adds more software you have to maintain, and more APIs you have to learn.

Answer (score 1):

CouchDB is relaxed. You can use `skip` for now. It will work pretty well and you can focus on other important things. The main problem is that it's not ultimately scalable. For small data sets (up to 1,000 rows or so), I wouldn't worry.

However, in the long term, this *will not* work well. Instead of setting `skip` to `0`, `20`, `40`, `60`, etc., you can use the `startkey` instead.

1. Query the first time, `startkey=substring`, `limit=20`.
2. Look at the final row in the result. The `key` tells you which key it used in the view.
3. So your next query will have `startkey=` the `key` value from step 2, plus `limit=20` and `skip=1`.

See what happened? The second query starts where the first query ends. To avoid showing the same row twice, you simply skip it. (You can also fetch it but ignore it on the client side—your choice.)

That works most of the time. I also suggest you look into `startkey_docid` described in the [CouchDB view API](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options).

Comment: when it does not work? If you emit multiple identical keys in the view?

Comment: I mean: "when you emit multiple identical keys for a given docid?"

Comment: The set of data is irregular, so 1 word (or substring of word) can be linked with undefined number of documents. And that number can be much more then size of page (ie word "book" can be linked with 100 docs, but page size 20) and starting from key "book" I can't show rest 80 docs and linked list will turn into infinite loop

Comment: in this document is really a lot - the current base for the conversion of the sql-based database of about 7,000,000

Comment: Right. You really need the `startkey_docid` stuff for scalability.